# Pass ng-content to child component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

thanks for your time.

I have three component:

1. Main page component
2. A button who use `angular/cdk/overlay` `overlay.create` to create the third component
3. A small box attached to the button who display text

The goal is to display information about the page when the user clicks on the button. I can't use `@Input`, cause the format (`h1`, `p`, component) of the information will change for each page.

#### My question

How can I pass HTML from the main component to the small box component?

or

How can I intercept the content of the `ng-content` and send it to the small box component?

*Main*

```html
<app-btn-info>
   <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
   <h1>Test</h1>
   <p>This is a test</p>
</app-btn-info>
```

*Button*

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-btn-info',
  templateUrl: './btn-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./btn-info.component.scss']
})
export class BtnInfoComponent {

  @ViewChild('button') button: MatIcon;

  constructor(private overlay: Overlay) { }

  public onClick() {
    this.overlay.create({
      positionStrategy: this.overlay.position().connectedTo(this.button._elementRef,
        { originX: 'start', originY: 'top' }, { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'top' }
      )
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<button #button mat-icon-button color="warn" matTooltip="Choose an option" (click)="onClick()">
    <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>
</button>
```

*Small box*

```html
<!-- From Main Component - But open by BtnInfoComponent -->
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Comment: Is small box component used in main component? can you post how are you using small box and which contents you want to pass?

Comment: I edit the question @NikhilWalvekar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference if anyone gets here, this may help -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-apjclv?file=src/app/child/child.component.html

Edit:

Basically, what you're looking for in the container:

```
<app-parent>
<span> some content from container </span>
</app-parent>
```

and in the parent:

```
<app-child>
  <ng-content select="[foo]" ngProjectAs="[foo]"> </ng-content>
</app-child>
```

and in the child:

```
<ng-content select="[foo]"> </ng-content>
```

Content can be added in the parent, but you'd need to split it up like:

```
<ng-container ngProjectAs="[foo]">
  <span>some parent content</span>
  <ng-content select="[foo]"></ng-content>
<ng-container>
```

---

Edit 2: So I got carried away with passing TemplateRefs, to have the ability to access variables from the component projecting the content (aka 'parent' in these examples). Accessing variables deeper than the 'parent' gets to be untenable however. If you need to access child variables, at that point I would suggest using a service/observable instead / rethinking your structure.

**TemplateRef Example**, using the same container/parent/child structure above:

```
// parent-foo.component.ts
@Input() templateFooSelector?: TemplateRef<any>;
```

```
<!-- container.component.html -->
<app-parent [templateFooSelector]="containerTemplate"></app-parent>

<ng-template #containerTemplate let-parentFoo="parentFoo">
  <div *ngIf="parentFoo.bar"> ParentFoo has variable Bar: {{parentFoo.bar}} </div>
</ng-template>
```

```
<!-- parent.component.html -->
<app-child>
  <!-- this ngProjectAs is only necessary if the child uses a 'select="..." ` -->
  <ng-container ngProjectAs="[childSelector]">
    <!-- the ngIfs may be unnecessary, haven't tested without -->
    <ng-content *ngIf="!templateFooSelector" select="[fooSelector]"></ng-content>
    <ng-container *ngIf="templateFooSelector">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateFooSelector; context: {parentFoo: this}">
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
<app-child>
```

Comment: Hi thanx a lot for this, you deserve +100

Comment: Worked like a charm, perfect :D

Answer (score -3):

You can pass html from main component to small box component using content projection. Please follow this link for how to use content projection https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/simplifying-content-projection-in-angular

Comment: Yes, I want to do this... But there is an intermediate component `BtnInfoComponent`, so how can I pass it to the small box